# What is the difference between export/import and provide/inject in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, es6-modules

In Vue3, what is the difference between export/import and provide/inject?

```js
// parent
const data = provide('data', ref(0))

// child
const data = inject('data')
```

```js
// parent
export const data = ref(0)

// child
import { data } from './parent'
```

I tried these two methods, and the performance results are the same.
I expect to know what is the difference between export/import and provide/inject?
and which one should be used in the actual project?

Comment: provide/inject is a form of DI. If injected value doesn't vary no matter what, even in tests, there's almost no practical difference, except that imports can cause circular deps that wouldn't happen otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vue 3, "provide" and "inject" are design patterns that allow you to pass data from a parent component to a child component. The "provide" method is used by a parent component to pass data to its children components and the "inject" method is used by a child component to receive the data from its parent.

On the other hand, "export" and "import" are used for modularization of code in JavaScript. "export" is used to make values and functions defined in a module available to other modules that import it, while "import" is used to import the exported values and functions into another module.

In other words, "provide" and "inject" are related to component communication within the same Vue app, while "export" and "import" are related to code modularization and sharing between different files.